# Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show me items from my Ignored Tags list?

Tags: discussion, tags, ignored-tags

When I click on "Unanswered Questions" in Stack Overflow,  adding  "Ignored Tags" such as "Javascript" and "iPhone" does not change the number of pages that return from the "Unanswered Questions" search.

Assuming the "Unanswered Questions" tab is actually showing all possible questions in the results, if I add ignored tags, I am expecting the number of pages returned to reduce but that doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: As noted something's wrong here, but does it matter if the number of pages changes?  You should care whether or not the questions that are displayed change, not whether there are enough questions being ignored to alter the pagination.

Comment: You point of view is interesting, and I agree with it, but still, I have the question.